# Error: File nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, express

```
nodemon : File C:\Users\saiful islam\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled 
on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon index.js
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to allow local scripts on your system?
Try opening Powershell as admin and paste this command.

> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

This ensures that locally executed scripts are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

i dont know if you are still looking for the answer.but somedays ago i ran in this same problem,for me it was bad command..please check,in your package.json file you have script like this..
`"scripts": { "start": "node index.js", "start-dev": "nodemon index.js", "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" },`
if it is,then in console give command.. npm run start-dev instead of node index.js or nodemon index.js..that solve my problem

Comment: That's the good answer. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your `nodemon.ps1` file located at `C:\Users\saiful islam\AppData\Roaming\npm` directory and rerun the `nodemon` command from the command prompt (`CMD` not from `PowerShell`) and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open this:
by press ctrl+( C:\Users\saiful islam\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1)
and it will ask you to install PowerShell and after that try to rerun the nodemon and hopely it wil work :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add this scripts to your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start-dev": "nodemon index.js"
  }
```

then type it to your console

> npm run start-dev